# Japanese audio books

Tags: discussion, resources

Is there any good sites for purchasing Japanese audio books, where a professional reads the content of modern novels? I tried searching for things like 朗読 and was unable to find much for modern works.

Could it be that audio books are just less popular in Japan than in somewhere like America?

There was an similar post on this several years back ([here](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/934/japanese-audio-resources-audiobook-streaming-audio)), however the site referred there seems to be down.

Amazon.co.jp seems to have an audiobook section, but I wasn't able to find any titles by any authors I was interested in, for example 村上春樹 or 東野圭吾 for which I would expect at least one work in audio form.

Comment: Last time I checked good オーディオブック are extremely rare. I did find the Harry Potter series extremely well done (i.e. well read); only the first two books were produced, though. I wasn't impressed by anything else I listened into. I would be interested to see if this has changed.

Comment: Harry Potter? Are you talking about English or Japanese translated version of it? If you mean in Japanese that is too bad. Maybe this is because it is hard to convey the nuances of Kanji in spoken words?

Comment: Yes, ハリー・ポッター in Japanese. This one I guess: [first book](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%80%8C%E3%83%8F%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%83%9D%E3%83%83%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A8%E8%B3%A2%E8%80%85%E3%81%AE%E7%9F%B3%E3%80%8D-CD-J%E3%83%BBK%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0/dp/4915512509)

Comment: [second book](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E7%AC%AC%E4%BA%8C%E5%B7%BB%E3%80%8C%E3%83%8F%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%83%9D%E3%83%83%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A8%E7%A7%98%E5%AF%86%E3%81%AE%E9%83%A8%E5%B1%8B%E3%80%8D-CD-J%E3%83%BBK%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0/dp/4915512568)

Comment: How about [英語で読む村上春樹](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/gogaku/english/yomu/), a radio program by NHK that can be listened to with [this app](https://www2.nhk.or.jp/gogaku/app/)? Both the Japanese and the English versions are read in the program, accompanied by interesting discussions on translation, nuances and story background.